# Reload iframe content when session variable changes

Tags: javascript, php

I'm making a webshop for a school project, and i've got an issue with the shopping cart. because the shoppingcart & webshop are in different iframes on the main page(got quite a few images on main page, don't want to reload that, thats why it's in iframes).

Basically, my issue is that when something is selected in the webshop, the shopping cart doesn't update untill the entire webpage is reloaded. I'm storing shopping cart info in an array in a SESSION variable. basically, what i want is to reload the iframe of the cart when the session variable changes.

If the answer involves anything besides PHP/javascript, please give a clear explaination/example code, i've never used anything outside of PHP/js/html/css before. Thanks in advance :) been stuck on this for a few days now :S

Comment: Sounds like you have some crazy application structure. Using iframes to hold your own application content === bad idea.

Comment: Suggestion: Create some javascript that checks a cookie value in a loop (this is all done locally in the browser), when you add a new item to the cart, alter this cookie with your php. when the javascript detects the change, refresh the page or re-fetch the cart contents.

Comment: watson - looking back at it, it indeed was a bad idea(looked like a gd solution a few months back :P). i'm only in high school, following IT as a voluntary subject, and we basically have to learn everything ourselves, all we get is an assignment. but we've made to much of the site now to change the entire structure. 

Scuzzy, you're my hero :) i never knew javascript could create cookies aswell, didnt think of that solution because i thought it wouldnt work with a PHP cookie

Comment: @user3362601 Thats cool, best of luck to you then :) But, as you might now realize, managing relationships between iframes is a pain, can bloat the size of your page and is best avoided unless you need to do something that literally can only be done by an iframe -- like css encapsulation, or embedding a page from another domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a javascript function to fire the following code when a user adds something to their cart:

```
document.getElementById('some_frame_id').contentWindow.location.reload();
```

Comment: is this possible to do from 1 iframe to another? because the shop is in 1 frame, and the cart is in another. both are displayed on the same page at the same time.

Comment: Yep, as long as it's the same domain. Otherwise you can use this:
document.getElementById('iframeid').src += '';

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code in front of me, but I've done something similar where in the parent you create an event listener on "message" then in the iframe you can call parent.postMessage, works as long as they are on the same domain

Answer (score 0):

Although APAD1's answer directly addresses what you asked, it sounds like your program has some deeper design problems. Using iframes for content from the same site (ie within one domain rather than content from a separate site) is bad practice.

Consider instead displaying content in `<div>`s with unique ids, and using javascript to update the contents of those divs. If you're using PHP on the back end, you can create a "page" that only generates the cart contents part of your page. Not only can you include it in each page without changes, but you can load it directly with javascript and insert the result into the current page to update it in place.

Whenever your user adds an item to their cart, you can call the javascript method that refreshes the `<div>` with the cart's contents.

Comment: yeah, the reason we used iframes was because we designed individual pages at first, with layout ready to use and such, and then we decided we wanted all on 1 page with changing content, so it looked like the easiest solution was to throw the already existing pages in an iFrame :S